# Socket arbitrarily connects - or doesnt

Tags: c, sockets, raspberry-pi, stream-socket-client

I'm working on a university project, in which I have to connect a raspberry pi to an Android smartphone to control 2 motors.
We are new to socket programming, so we started out with an example we found on wikibooks and tried to modify in to our needs. We're now facing the problem, that the connection between server and client is very arbitrary and unstable, sometimes connecting, and after a brief disconnect doesnt connect again. The weird thing (for me) is, that after we edit the code above the part responsible for connection:

```
 /* bind serv information to mysocket */
bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

/* start listening, allowing a queue of up to 2 pending connection */
listen(mysocket, 2);
consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
```

like inserting in a printf, the next time we launch the programm, everthing does work, sometimes two or three times, and then it just stops connecting.

I've searched all over google and so for a similar problem, but I haven't found an equivalent, so I turn to you directly now.

This is code for our server running on the raspberry pi, which also serves as a network hotspot:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bcm2835.h>

#define PORTNUM 5298
#define MAXRCVLEN 1000

#define PIN9 RPI_GPIO_P1_21
#define PIN10 RPI_GPIO_P1_19
#define PIN11 RPI_GPIO_P1_23
#define PIN22 RPI_GPIO_P1_15


int setpins();
int forward();
int backward();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char msg[] = "Connected!\n";
char testchar[] = "stillthere?";
char quitstring[] = "quit";   
char *recbuf; 

int qflag = 0;
int lflag = 0;
int mysocket, consocket, len;       /* socket used to listen for incoming connections */

struct sockaddr_in dest;        /* socket info about the machine connecting to us */
struct sockaddr_in serv;        /* socket info about our server */

socklen_t socksize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);


memset(&serv, 0, sizeof(serv));           /* zero the struct before filling the fields */
serv.sin_family = AF_INET;                /* set the type of connection to TCP/IP */
serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* set our address to any interface */
serv.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);           /* set the server port number */

mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

/* bind serv information to mysocket */
bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
/* start listening, allowing a queue of up to 2 pending connection */
listen(mysocket, 2);
consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);


if (!bcm2835_init())   return 1;

setpins();
while(consocket)
{
    printf("Incoming connection from %s - sending welcome\n", inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
    send(consocket, msg, strlen(msg), 0);

    while (!qflag && !lflag) {

        // Do something when connection is lost: SO_KEEPALIVE?
    // if (!send(consocket,testchar, strlen(testchar), 0)) lflag = 1;
            recbuf = malloc (MAXRCVLEN+1);
            len = recv(consocket, recbuf, MAXRCVLEN, 0);
            recbuf[len] = '\0';

    if (len > 0) printf("Client sent %s (%d bytes). \n", recbuf, len);
            if (recbuf[0] == 'v') forward(); // this function lets our car drive forward
            if (recbuf[0] == 'r') backward();// this one backwards ;)
    // Leave this loop if the client sends you the quitstring
            if (!strcmp (recbuf, quitstring))     qflag = 1;

    free(recbuf);
    }   

if (qflag) break;
    listen(mysocket, 1);
    consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
}

close(consocket);
close(mysocket);
printf("sockets closed\n");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

One line in there

```
 // if (!send(consocket,testchar, strlen(testchar), 0)) lflag = 1;
```

is our idea to test wether the connection is still up, is this viable?

And this is the client code, thats not in Java yet but in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define MAXRCVLEN 500
#define PORTNUM 5298

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char buffer[MAXRCVLEN + 1]; /* +1 so we can add null terminator */
   int len, mysocket;
   struct sockaddr_in dest; 

   mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));                /* zero the struct */
   dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
   dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.42.1"); /* set destination IP number */ 
   dest.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);                /* set destination port number */

   do {
    connect(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    len = recv(mysocket, buffer, MAXRCVLEN, 0);
   }while(len < 0);
   /* We have to null terminate the received data ourselves */
   buffer[len] = '\0';

   // Received
   printf("Received %s (%d bytes).\n", buffer, len);

   // send:
   char msg[] = " ";
    do{
    scanf("%s",msg);    
    printf("Sending Msg to %s \n", inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
    send( mysocket, msg, strlen(msg),0);
    }while (strcmp(msg,"quit"));


   close(mysocket);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any ideas what we did wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Always check the return codes of all relevant system calls.

Comment: Closely read the man-pages for recv()/send() and learn that at least for sockets those two functions do not necessarily receive/send as much bytes as they were told to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data had been received/sent is a good idea, not to say an essential necessity.

Comment: Also the case of `read()` returning `0` shall be handled seperatly as it indicates that the other side `close()`ed the connection.

Comment: Yeah, I read through the documentation of these, we didnt include error checking just yet because it was the end of a long day and we "just" wanted to get the connection working, I guess you shouldnt leave error checking out of nothing... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless what you actually, really want to learn is low-level berkeley socket manipulation, I'd suggest you look at [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or a similar library.

The structure of your main loop is a little unusual. You can clearly only handle one connection at a time, and you don't cope well with any connection attempts that happened while you were servicing a previous connection.

```
bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

bind can fail, e.g. if another process has recently had the socket open and the OS hasn't finished cleaning up use of the port. You can change this behavior, but you should still check, from [die.net's bind manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind)

```
Return Value
  On success, zero is returned. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.
```

so

```
if(bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr))) {
    perror("bind failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

listen() only needs to be called once, but also needs to be checked

```
if(listen(mysocket, 2)) {
    perror("listen failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

after this, if you are content to do the single-service approach, then you can do the following:

```
mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(mysocket < 0) {
    perror("socket failed");
    exit(1);
}

if(bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr))) {
    perror("bind failed");
    exit(1);
}

if(listen(mysocket, 2)) {
    perror("listen failed");
    exit(1);
}

for (;;) {
    consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
    if(consocket < 0) // might return if the connection has already gone away.
        continue;
    if (!sendGreeting(consocket)) {
        // sendGreeting should return -1 if it was unable to send, 0 if successful
        while (!readLoop(consocket, recvBuf, MAXRCVLEN))
            ;
    }
    close(consocket);
}
```

readLoop would then be something like:

```
int readLoop(int socket, char* buffer, size_t bufSize) {
    int len = recv(socket, buffer, bufSize);
    if (len > 0)
        return processBuffer(socket, buffer, len);
    if (len < 0 && (errno == EINTR || errno == EAGAIN))
        return 0; // do-over
    return -1;
}
```

make sure that processBuffer also returns 0 or -1 accordingly.

As I mentioned above, there are still problems with this approach, but it's not my intent here to teach you everything you need to know about sockets in one pass :) If you want to further develop your socket knowledge, your next stop should be learning about [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) with non-blocking sockets so that you can host multiple sockets and service them as they become active.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for that detailled answer! We're gonna try this in a few hours when we have time assigned for that. I guess the reason it sometimes connected and sometimes didnt was, because the OS didnt really close the sockets and we didnt error check.

Comment: Alright, we put in most of the changes you suggested, except of a processBuffer method, because we don't really get what it's supposed to do. I mean, recv already writes all recieved bytes to buffer, so why not just return len? What is supposed to happen within processBuffer that requires socket again?

Comment: It might want to ‘send()‘ a response. processBuffer would be where you inspect the recv'd data and choose a reaction.

Comment: Ah, ok, sending a response, we didnt even think about that! :D
Yes, we put our reaction to the data in there, but we left the socket out, because since it's gonna be a remotely controlled car, there is no need :)
Thank a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should use `tcpdump`/`wireshark` to see what packets are seen by you Rpi, and `strace` to see what your program does. My first guess about your connections sometimes not working would be loss of packets. By using wired LAN (Ethernet), you could rule this possibility out.

But the example server code that you're using is a rather bad example. Even if you only want to accept a single client connection at a time, your server should not use blocking waits for any remote message. You should read about using non-blocking I/O, `select` or `poll`, and look at examples using these. Also, please read about `SO_REUSEADDR`, you probably need that one in your server as well.

Comment: I definitely will read about about select and polling, those didnt even come up in the tutorials I read...

Answer (score 0):

This line code

```
char msg[] = " ";
do{
  scanf("%s",msg);
```

will fail miserably if the number of bytes scanned in is larger then 1 character, as `msg` provides exactly two bytes (from which one is always used as `0`-terminator). Feeding more would write out of the bounds of `msg` and doing so will provoke undefined behaviuor.

To fix this providing at least a minimum of 255 characters to so:

```
char msg[256] = "";
do{
  scanf("%255s",msg);
```

Comment: Yeah, we didnt really think about that because it's kind of a remainder of the reference code we used and modified, I don't think it's gonna make it in the final :)
Thanks :)